# How to generate an array in Vue and then use v-model on an item within the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am generating an array using data fetched from an api, which returns a size; I use this size to build the array inserting an object `{ selected: null }`.

Looping through this in my view I am generating select elements which I am then binding to selected. Unfortunately, generating the array causes ALL of the selects to change, rather than just one.

As seen in the jsfiddle below, if the array is built directly into the data it works fine, but generating it via a method does not work as required.

https://jsfiddle.net/Crotanite/gh50s39e/

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not an issue of `method()`, `method()` shall behave the same as `data()` in this scenario.

The real issue is with the javascript method -> `.fill()` as it creates a reference pointer to all the items in the array. This may be a good read - [JS pass by ref vs pass by val](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c)

I tried a workaround, avoided using `.fill()`, instead filled the array by a simple loop in `method()`. Attaching a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivampesitbng/g8pxu0Lz/1/) link with a working example for the same.